# Got an error in Express, cant send request

Tags: mongodb, express, ecmascript-6

controllers/userController.js

```
import User from '../models/userModel.js'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import generateToken from '../utils/generateToken.js'

// @desc    Auth user & get token
// @route   POST /api/users/login
// @access  Public
const authUser = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body

  const user = await User.findOne({ email })
  if(user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id)
    })
  } else  {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Invalid email or Password')
  }
})

// @desc    Get user Profile
// @route   GET /api/users/login
// @access  Private
const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  // res.json(req.user)
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)
  console.log('user', user)
  if (user) {
    res.json(user)
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('User not Found')
  }
})

export { authUser, getUserProfile }
```

middleware/errorMiddleWare.js

```
const notFound = (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`)
  res.status(404)
  next(error)
}

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode
  res.status(statusCode)
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack
  })
}

export { notFound, errorHandler }
```

middleware/authMiddleware.js

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

const protect = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
  let token
  if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
      const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')
      next()
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401)
      throw new Error('Not Authorized, token failed')
    }
  }

  if(!token) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Not Authorized')
  }
  next()
})
export { protect }
```

routes/userRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()
import { authUser, getUserProfile } from '../controllers/userController.js'
import { protect } from '../middleware/authMiddleware.js'

router.post('/login', authUser)
router.route('/profile').get(protect, getUserProfile)

export default router
```

I got an error in userController.js, error from my errorMiddleware.
Scenario :

1. If I send a response from "if statement". (after User.findById)
   [image]
2. But if I send response before "if statement", it work (is not Good). But why? and how can I solve this (to send a response after using User.findById) ?
3. I got an Error in server console when I used scenario 1 or 2.
   [image]

version
node 14.12.0
express 4.17.1

Comment: Have you imported User Model in your controller like this?
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

And please show the protect middleware code. I think there might be an issue.

Comment: yeah @IbadShaikh. I edited my post.

Comment: Inside the server console, it is pointing out error at userController.js at line 34. Check there if you have sent headers twice.

Answer (score 1):

Done, I forgot to delete `next()` in middleware/authMiddleware.js to protect getUserProfile.